# android test alarm - can't activate it

Tags: android, timer, alert

I set an alarm in my app to notify the user. I want to test it but can't figure out how to set it to the current time + 2 minutes. How can I do it?

Here's my code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , PopupWin.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  //  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
   // calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
   // calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis((int)((calendar.getTimeInMillis()+calendar.getTimeZone().getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()))/1000));

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fire alarm for two minutes from current time do this,

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (calendar.getTimeInMillis()+(60*2*1000)) , operation);
```

Comment: awesomeness, you dear sir, deserve a cooki!

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying to create a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)?

Add this field first:

```
private static int delayTime = 2*60*1000 // interval time before the execution of your code is started (in millisecond)
```

To execute your code after 2 minutes from now:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        notifyUser(); // notify the user
    }
}, delayTime);
```